My Fingerprint Not Working
I use Asus Vivobook M1403QA running on Ubuntu 22.04 and when i enroll the fingerprint it says failed to enroll new fingerprint. when i try again it says the same, and after i tried again it says fingerprint device disconnected. please help me

The Asus Vivobook M1403QA has a fingerprint reader integrated into the touchpad. To use it, place your finger on the designated area of the touchpad. If the designated area of the touchpad is dirty then a new fingerprint cannot be enrolled, so clean the touchpad and most likely it will work like new.
